# Current and voltage - Incompatibility between Ohm's Law and Power Law!

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage

Ohm's Law: I $=\frac{V}{R}$: Increasing voltage increases current.

Power Law: P $={V}*{I}$: Increasing voltage decreases current.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri It does not exactly, as my doubts are slightly different.

Comment: @ElFlea In what way are your doubts different?

Comment: @sammygerbil Why must you always be on the lookout, wanting to close my questions. You already closed two of my questions for being "off-topic".

Comment: Nothing personal! I am not the only user voting to close your questions.11 others have voted. 3 other users also voted to close 2 of your 5 closed questions. And 3 more have voted to close 3 of your questions. ... You have had 3 answers, one of which you have accepted.

Comment: @sammygerbil If a question got answers, it's got to stay. Others have put effort into answering it.

Comment: Closing a question does not schedule it for deletion. The question and answers remain indefinitely on the site. Both can be edited, voted for and commented on. The only restriction is that no new answers can be posted. This is to encourage answers to be posted on the earlier question. ... That question would have been suggested to you when you were posting yours. You should always look at the suggestions which are given to see if any answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others say, you are implicitly holding one factor constant and seeing how the others are related but a different constant factor in each case.

A real world example may help.  Consider an old style filament light bulb.  It is intended to be used in a $220V$ country and consume $110W$.  So, it should draw $0.5A$ and needs a resistance of $440 \Omega$.

We can keep the resistance constant and vary the voltage by taking it to a $110V$ country.  Ohm's law tells us that it will now draw only $0.25A$ hence the power will be only $27.5W$.

For the constant power scenario, imagine that the manufacturer wants to make a similar $110W$ bulb for $110V$ countries.  He needs it to draw $1A$ so he must arrange for its resistance to be $110 \Omega$.  Note that this will be a different bulb.

For some fun, take the bulb intended for $110V$ to a $220V$ country.  I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: God Bless people who give examples! Makes it so easy to understand.

Comment: For the exercise, I suppose the bulb, as its resistance is fixed, will burn out? Or maybe it glows way too brightly? :)

Comment: If we pretend that it will cope then it will draw $2A$ and hence $440W$.  Four times its design load.  It will probably glow very brightly for a short while before going pop.  Don't try this at home.  I have seen it in the Philippines where they use US style plugs and sockets but $220V$. It looks as if you can use US devices but you can't.

Comment: Some modern devices, e.g. phone chargers and laptop power supplies, will seem to disobey this.  However, they use more complex components and don't obey Ohm' s law.  That's why I used an old style filament light bulb for my example.

Answer (score 4):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, you are missing what is held constant in each case.

> Ohm's Law: I=V/R. Increasing voltage increases current.

Should read “Increasing voltage increases current for a fixed resistance.”

> Power Law: P =∗. Increasing voltage decreases current.

Should read “Increasing voltage decreases current for a fixed power.”

The two statements are not contradictory since they refer to different scenarios. Usually resistance is fixed and power is not.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed that power does change since voltage is changing, the easiest way to see it is to rewrite P = V*I = V*(V/R) = (V^2)/R.
  So , as you see if voltage is increasing the current is increasing and power is increasing as well.